# Cloudflare Pages Sveltekit Build failed with possible error in Auth.js

Tags: cloudflare-pages

I am trying to deploy a SvelteKit project from Github. It uses Auth.js and for previous successful deployments in vercel, I had to use latest node version (20.x) for Auth.js to work.

Node version: 20.11.0

Build command: npm run build

Build script: vite build

Build directory: /.svelte-kit/cloudflare

Build System version: 2

In the logs, the specified line 50 in hooks.server.js is trying to read a property: `basePath.length`. `basePath` is eventually set from the config parameter passed to `SvelteKitAuth()` function, an Auth.js library function. Auth.js by default sets it to `"/auth"`.

This same configuration worked in Vercel.
I have tried setting basePath to default value in code but the error still remains.
The log parts related to the failure is given below:

```
23:15:18.367    Successfully installed @sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare.
23:15:18.368    
23:15:18.368    If you plan on staying on this deployment platform, consider replacing @sveltejs/adapter-auto with @sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare. This will give you faster and more robust installs, and more control over deployment configuration.
23:15:18.369    
23:15:19.038    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
23:15:19.038        at Object.handle (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/hooks.server.js:50:24)
23:15:19.038        at respond (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2586:43)
23:15:19.038        at Server.respond (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2849:12)
23:15:19.039        at generate_fallback (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/fallback.js:38:32)
23:15:19.039        at async MessagePort.<anonymous> (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/utils/fork.js:22:16)
23:15:19.044    
23:15:19.044    node:internal/event_target:1100
23:15:19.044      process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
23:15:19.044                               ^
23:15:19.046    Error: Could not create a fallback page — failed with status 500
23:15:19.046        at generate_fallback (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/fallback.js:53:8)
23:15:19.046        at async MessagePort.<anonymous> (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/utils/fork.js:22:16)
23:15:19.046    Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
23:15:19.047        at [kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:326:10)
23:15:19.047        at [kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:337:37)
23:15:19.047        at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:232:57)
23:15:19.047        at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:826:20)
23:15:19.047        at exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
23:15:19.047    
23:15:19.047    Node.js v20.11.0
23:15:19.124    Failed: Error while executing user command. Exited with error code: 1
23:15:19.135    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
23:15:20.267    Failed: error occurred while running build command
```

I can provide more details if needed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

What I did so far:
Changed Node version to latest from the default value.
Assigned `"/auth"` to `SvelteKitAuth()` function's `config` parameter property `basePath`.

Expected:
The build should work with the given node version. It worked in Vercel.

Update:
I could not get my project to build in cloudflare pages. It seems that the problem is somewhat related with cloudflare build environments inherent node version. In vercel, node 20.x is experimentally allowed. But in cloudflare pages, I had to setup a NODE_VERSION environment variable to get to node 20.x. This is the only difference between my successful vercel build and the failed cloudflare pages build.